# Compile Cyanogenmod Windows bash

Tags: android, bash, cyanogenmod

I am trying to compile cyanogenmod in windows with its new bash
I have downloaded the source code from here

[Compressed Android Source Code xda](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/sources-android-sources-highly-t3231109)

I have also downloaded all the required tools in bash but whenever i try to do `repo sync`
It returns this error

`error: .repo/manifests/: contains uncommitted changes`

Can Anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have changed a file within .repo/manifests/ and this hasn't been committed. You can use `repo status` or `repo diff` to identify which files have been changed.

If you don't think you changed anything, try running:

`git reset --hard
repo sync`

Comment: I tried git reset --hard but still got the same error

Comment: Repo diff shows that 4 files have been modified. I have used the same source tar.xy in ubuntu and it doesn't show any error. I am getting this error only on windows bash.